# muix datagrid - creating custom filter with range of date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

is it possible to create a custom data range filter on MUIX data grid? so far i have tried few resources to no avail. i expect that I can pick 2 dates and the filter will show result of those within those 2 date i'm new to this so appreciate for the help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.